# Ember set for Object and arrays

Tags: arrays, object, ember.js

In Ember,

```
var Test = Ember.Object.create({
name: "Ember",
changeableName: "",
resetName: function() {
this.set('changeableName', this.get('name'));
}
});

Test.resetName();
Test.get('changeableName');      // Ember
Test.get('name');      // Ember
Test.set('changeableName', "Ember Test");      
Test.get('changeableName');      // Ember Test
Test.get('name');      // Ember
```

This works well and it is expected behaviour.

But if I use object or array in this way it reflects change back to the original property,

```
var Test = Ember.Object.create({ 
nameObj: {"name":"Ember"}, 
changeableName: {}, 
resetName: function() { this.set('changeableName', this.get('nameObj')); } 
});

Test.resetName(); 
Test.get('changeableName.name');      // Ember 
Test.get('nameObj.name');      // Ember 
Test.set('changeableName.name', "Ember Test");       
Test.get('changeableName.name');      // Ember Test 
Test.get('nameObj.name');      // Ember Test
```

This is not fair. I don't want the change reflected back to original object.Ember.set works well for primitive types but for object and array it is not I wanted.

Is there any work around for this kinda cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say that this is unfair. **This is exactly how Objects and Object references work** :-)

This is what you basically want to do:

- There is a property which contains an Object that may be modified.
- There is a reset function, that should reset the aforementioned property to the values specified within some kind of template object (=nameObj).

But here is what you do in your code:

- The property changeableName is set to point towards nameObj.
- You make changes on the object.
- Again you set the property changeableName to point towards nameObj.

You see the problem right? You have to adapt the reset function to always create a new object based on your "template object" (nameObj). The following code should do it :-)

```
var Test = Ember.Object.create({ 
nameObj: {"name":"Ember"}, 
changeableName: {}, 
resetName: function() {
  var hash = this.get('nameObj');
  this.set('changeableName', Ember.Object.create(hash)); 
} 
});
Test.resetName(); 
Test.get('changeableName.name');      // Ember 
Test.get('nameObj.name');      // Ember 
Test.set('changeableName.name', "Ember Test");       
Test.get('changeableName.name');      // Ember Test 
Test.get('nameObj.name');      // Ember
```